# Extraer puntos dentro de un polígono, Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

Buen día a todos;

Estoy intentando extraer valores de (x,y) de puntos que se encuentran dentro de un polígono.

```
DF2 = 
Coord_X     Coord_Y
 773686.694500  9963113.176875
 773695.107375  9963167.598125
 773707.252750  9963146.229750
 773694.324000  9963092.721625
 773686.197375  9963082.305875
 773687.040875  9963167.699125
 773727.531625  9963101.132000
 773659.458625  9963152.513625
 773696.472625  9963155.930750
 773639.421625  9963091.894250
 773639.421625  9963080.668875
 773746.696125  9963121.726250
 773667.951000  9963060.118625
 773688.386375  9963140.699875
 773694.572625  9963133.687500
 773695.140250  9963177.481500
 773694.225000  9963067.096375
 773686.595000  9963102.952500
 773639.401375  9963111.634000
 773648.363250  9963113.248875
 773640.049375  9963131.062375
 773640.697750  9963141.208375
 773649.267000  9963122.730250
 773694.508250  9963103.219125
 773662.812625  9963144.331125
 773640.265375  9963123.938500
 773653.061250  9963168.799625
 773740.705500  9963102.361000
 773639.853875  9963103.983125
 773663.669000  9963141.736250
 773656.719750  9963105.392750
 773721.230250  9963148.101000
 773705.000000  9963176.000000
 773754.354000  9963120.056625
 773699.880250  9963085.736625
 773686.694500  9963113.176875
 773695.107375  9963167.598125
 773727.531625  9963101.132000
 773696.472625  9963155.930750
 773688.386375  9963140.699875
 773694.572625  9963133.687500
 773694.225000  9963067.096375
 773639.401375  9963111.634000
 773640.697750  9963141.208375
 773640.265375  9963123.938500
 773740.705500  9963102.361000
 773705.000000  9963176.000000
 773727.531625  9963101.132000
 773688.386375  9963140.699875
 773694.572625  9963133.687500
 773694.225000  9963067.096375
 773639.401375  9963111.634000
 773640.697750  9963141.208375
 773640.265375  9963123.938500
 773727.531625  9963101.132000
```

El código es:

```py
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

poly = Polygon([[773642.25342880527, 9963094.3392374925],
        [773662.7163213623, 9963189.5526211839],
        [773773.26644345513, 9963191.592321692],
        [773771.91631169291, 9963098.0998664293],
        [773667.59566028137, 9963054.4342967868]])
x,y = poly.exterior.xy
plt.scatter(DF2["Coord_X"], DF2["Coord_Y"], marker='+',linewidth=1,c="r", s=90)
plt.plot(x, y, color='y', alpha=2, linewidth=2, solid_capstyle='round', zorder=2) 
plt.show()
```

Si dibujamos el polígono y los puntos, se muestran a continuación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podría extraer solo puntos que se encuentran dentro del polígono, tal vez alguien tiene alguna idea, muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: No tiene mucho que ver con la pregunta, pero te recomiendo profundamente cambiar a python 3.X porque cada vez 2.X tiene menos soporte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás usando `shapely` y esa biblioteca ya te da las herramientas necesarias para verificar si un punto dado está o no dentro de un polígono dado:

```
polygon.contains(Point(x,y))
```

Sólo hay que juntar esto con pandas para filtrar todas aquellas filas en las que esa condición sea cierta. En tu caso, veo que tienes todos los datos en un dataframe llamado `DF2`, por lo que podrías hacer:

```py
dentro = DF2[DF2.apply(lambda row: poly.contains(Point(row.Coord_X, row.Coord_Y)), 
                       axis=1)]
```

Básicamente, `DF2.apply(lambda, axis=1)` aplica la función lambda en cuestión a cada fila del dataframe, y devuelve una Serie con el resultado de cada ejecución. Lo que hacemos es esa lambda llamar a `poly.contains()`, creando un `Point` con las coordenadas extraidas de esa fila. El resultado de cada llamada a la `lambda` será `True` o `False`, por lo que al final el `DF2.apply()` te retorna una serie (columna) de `True`s y `False`s. Aplicamos eso como índice de `DF2[]` para seleccionar sólo aquellas filas en que haya salido `True`.

El resultado son ya sólo las filas que corresponden a puntos dentro del polígono.

Para demostrarlo, voy a pintar con una X azul todos los puntos de `DF2` y con un punto rojo todos los puntos del dataframe resultante `dentro` (además del polígono en amarillo):

```
ax = df.plot(x="Coord_X", y="Coord_Y", kind="scatter", marker="x", color="blue")
x,y = poly.exterior.xy
ax.plot(x, y, color='yellow', alpha=2, linewidth=2, solid_capstyle='round', zorder=2)
dentro.plot(x="Coord_X", y="Coord_Y", kind="scatter", color="red", marker=".", ax=ax)
```

y este es el resultado:

[image: Resultado]